# Database design: Postgres or EAV to hold semi-structured data

Tags: mongodb, postgresql, laravel, entity-attribute-value, hstore

I was given the task to decide whether our stack of technologies is adequate to complete the project we have at hand or should we change it (and to which technologies exactly).

The problem is that I'm just a SQL Server DBA and I have a few days to come up with a solution...

#### This is what our client wants:

They want a web application to centralize pharmaceutical researches separated into topics, or projects, in their jargon. These researches are sent as csv files and they are somewhat structured as follows:

- **Project** (just a name for the project)
- **Segment** (could be behavioral, toxicology, etc. There is a finite set of about 10 segments. Each csv file holds a segment)
- **Mandatory fixed fields** (a small set of fields that are always present, like Date, subjects IDs, etc. These will be the PKs).
- **Dynamic fields** (could be anything here, but always as a key/pair value and shouldn't be more than 200 fields)
- Whatever **files** (images, PDFs, etc.) that are associated with the project.
  At the moment, they just want to store these files and retrieve them through a simple search mechanism.

They don't want to crunch the numbers at this point.
98% of the files have a couple of thousand lines, but there's a 2% with a couple of million rows (and around 200 fields).

#### This is what we are developing so far:

The back-end is SQL 2008R2. I've designed EAVs for each segment (before anything please keep in mind that this is not our first EAV design. It worked well before with less data.) and the mid-tier/front-end is PHP 5.3 and Laravel 4 framework with Bootstrap.
The issue we are experiencing is that PHP chokes up with the big files. It can't insert into SQL in a timely fashion when there's more than 100k rows and that's because there's a lot of pivoting involved and, on top of that, PHP needs to get back all the fields IDs first to start inserting. I'll explain: this is necessary because the client wants some sort of control on the fields names. We created a repository for all the possible fields to try and minimize ambiguity problems; fields, for instance, named as "Blood Pressure", "BP", "BloodPressure" or "Blood-Pressure" should all be stored under the same name in the database. So, to minimize the issue, the user has to actually insert his csv fields into another table first, we called it properties table. This action won't completely solve the problem, but as he's inserting the fields, he's seeing possible matches already inserted. When the user types in blood, there's a panel showing all the fields already used with the word blood. If the user thinks it's the same thing, he has to change the csv header to the  field. Anyway, all this is to explain that's not a simple EAV structure and there's a lot of back and forth of IDs.

This issue is giving us second thoughts about our technologies stack choice, but we have limitations on our possible choices: I only have worked with relational DBs so far, only SQL Server actually and the other guys know only PHP. I guess a MS full stack is out of the question. 
It seems to me that a non-SQL approach would be the best. I read a lot about MongoDB but honestly, I think it would be a super steep learning curve for us and if they want to start crunching the numbers or even to have some reporting capabilities,

I guess Mongo wouldn't be up to that. I'm reading about PostgreSQL which is relational and it's famous HStore type. So here is where my questions start:

> - Would you guys think that Postgres would be a better fit than SQL Server for this project?
> - Would we be able to convert the csv files into JSON objects or whatever to be stored into HStore fields and be somewhat queryable?
> - Is there any issues with Postgres sitting in a windows box? I don't think our client has Linux admins. Nor have we for that matter...
> - Is it's licensing free for commercial applications?
> - Or should we stick with what we have and try to sort the problem out with staging tables or bulk-insert or other technique that relies on the back-end to do the heavy lifting?

Sorry for the long post and thanks for your input guys, I appreciate all answers as I'm pulling my hair out here :)

Comment: Bite the bullet and go for a nosql solution. The steep slope of the learning curve is something you'll ave to clamber up once. EAV and a relational database, change your name to Sisyphus...

Comment: Ahem. Read these. Your post is going to get flagged and closed. http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Good question, but really off topic for Stack Overflow. Frankly, it sounds like changing your stack is premature; even PHP + MSSQL should be able to deal with this kind of thing pretty painlessly (though querying the EAV data back out might suck). As for Pg: Yes, hstore would probably be useful here, but 9.4+'s `json` will be better when 9.4 is released. Pg runs fine on Windows. There's an FAQ about the license, read that, and read the license (short: BSD = $0 everywhere, open source nonviral). Even as a dedicated Pg user, I think it's stupid to change right now, your issues aren't in the DB.

Comment: Try posting more specific questions (you can link to this one as background). You say PHP is "choking up". How so / why? Raise this, specifically, as a single concrete problem, with appropriate detail.

Comment: Thanks Craig! I think you are right. Although I guess querying data out of `json` might be hard too, no? Our issues are not in the DB and we lack some sort of background queue on PHP to deal with the waiting times, so the user won't be staring at the screen for 20 minutes to know if the importer succeeded...